# Change of variables for an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, change-of-variable

I have an integral where I need to change variables. The integral has the form,

$\int_0^x f(x,t) dt$ .

I change variables/rescale by setting $\tilde{t}=xt$, which means $d\tilde{t}=xdt$. Would the new integral have the following form & bounds:

$\int_0^{x^2} f(x,\tilde{t}) d\tilde{t}$ ?

Comment: Why did you substitute $t$ with $\tilde{t}$ directly, clearly $t = \tilde{t}/x$.

Comment: You have $\int_0^x f(x, t)dt$ and you want to make the change of variable $s= xt$.  Yes, $ds= x dt$ so that $dt= \frac{1}{x}ds$.  When t= 0, s= 0 and wen t= x, $s= x^2$.  The integral is $\frac{1}{x}\int_0^{x^2} f(x, s/x)ds$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly computed, $d\widetilde{t}=xdt$, so $dt=d\widetilde{t}/x$. We can see by $\widetilde{t}=xt$ that $0\le t\le x$ means that $0\le \widetilde{t}\le x^2$ using $\widetilde{t}/x=t$. Plugging this all in, we get
$$ \int_0^x f(x,t)dt=\int_0^{x^2} \frac{f(x,\widetilde{t}/x)}{x}d\widetilde{t}.$$

Comment: What about the argument of $f$?

Comment: You're right, of course.